# Generated sources by JOOQ are not being compiled when skipping JOOQ

Tags: java, maven, jooq

We use `spring boot` and `Jooq` together in our project, and we are setting a Gitlab CI/CD process with `build`, `test`, `deploy` phases.

We found that Jooq can be a bit challenging when setting up the CI/CD process since we have to spin up a dockerized db specifically to run jooq.

Basically, our steps in the `build` phase in Gitlab CI are:

- Spin up a dockerized db
- Execute flyway: `mvn flyway:migrate ...`
- Run `mvn package -DskipTests` (which runs `jooq` to generate the code)
- Cache `target/`

So far so good, however the next CI/CD job is the `Test` phase, where we do:

- Pull `target/` from cache
- Run `mvn test -DskipJooq=true`

Since `mvn package` already executed jooq to generate sources the problem we have is that when calling `mvn test -DskipJooq=true` JOOQ does not do anything, but we still need `jooq` to compile the generated java files.

I couldn't find anything related to this. Is there any way to achieve that?

For the moment, we solved this by spinning up the db, running flyway and jooq again in the test phase (the same process we have in `build` phase), but this looks like unnecessary if we could make jooq to compile the generated sources.

Comment: Are you caching both the generated sources *and* compiled classes?

Comment: @LukasEder I'm caching the full `/target/*` directory and using same `target/generated-sources/jooq` to store generated .java files. So, in the `test` job jooq generated code it's there, however not being compiled